# Push Notifications not working when app is killed

Tags: iphone, xcode, push-notification, app-store-connect, native

I made an app in react native and used this library for push notifications:
https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

When I run my iphone app using the command, 'react-native run-ios', an iphone 6 simulator pops up with my app running and when I kill the app, i still get notifications. However, when I run my program from xcode, it opens up a similar iphone 6 simulator, but now when the app is killed, notifications do not work. However, the weird thing is that notifications do work when I close the app (aka going to home screen) then killing the app when running w/ xcode. I started getting this problem on xcode when I got ready to publish my app on the app store and needed to get a push notification certificate. I also enabled push notifications in the 'Capabilities' in my xcode project and I also have the push notifications enabled in my developer provisioning files. The push notifications are enabled for both development and production, and I am receiving push notifications when the user exits the app using the home button and then kills the application, but if the user kills the application without pressing the home button first, i do not receive notifications. I do not know what to do.

Comment: Are you killing the app the exact same way in both cases (the double tapping on home button technique)?

Comment: yeah i am killing the app by touble tapping home screen twice and sliding up

Answer (score 1):

When an app is killed notification will be handled from the operating system so it needs some specific key to display the notification. Your json should be like below

```
{
    "content_available": 1, 
      "notification": {
        "title":  "Mark sent you a message", 
        "sound": "default", 
        "body": "Hello", 
        "badge": 0

      } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm surprised you are receiving notifications at all when the app is force quit (double tapping on the home button and swiping up).

See [Understanding When Your App Gets Launched in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7) of the *App Programming Guide for iOS: Background Execution,* which touches on caveats regarding force quitting an app.

> Apps that support background execution may be relaunched by the system to handle incoming events. If an app is terminated for any reason other than the user force quitting it, the system launches the app when one of the following events happens: ...
>
> In most cases, the system does not relaunch apps after they are force quit by the user. One exception is location apps, ... In other cases, though, the user must launch the app

The [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1) says

> On an iOS device, if a user force-quits your app using the app multitasking UI, the app does not receive remote notifications until the user relaunches it.

Comment: Your app will not get launched but the push notifications will still show up.

Comment: "The app does not receive remote notifications until the user relaunches it" - This statement is not exactly correct. Remote notifications are received on the device but the "didReceiveRemoteNotification" method is not called when the app is killed by force quit. Check the below link for more info.  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65817

Comment: Sure, but they’re not received by the force-quit app until the user relaunches the it.